# How to send SMS in laravel

Tags: laravel, sms

I created a food ordering system using Laravel. Now I want to send confirmation SMS automatically to the customer when their order received I am creating this project as my university project, not for commercial use so are there any free services that can I use?

Comment: You need to use a SMS gateway. Contact your mobile providers or a middle portal in your location to get that.

Answer (score 3):

These types of services almost always have a cost. They have been created via someone's time and efforts, and they charge for this.

That being said, there are some VERY cheap options out there. Here are probably the top 2:

- [Twilio](https://go.twilio.com/sms/?pdv=c&pcrid=255773362479&pmt=e&pkw=twilio%20sms&campaign=G_S_Brand_Alpha_NA&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=twilio%20sms&utm_campaign=G_S_Brand_Alpha_NA&utm_content=Brand&gclid=Cj0KCQjwqsHWBRDsARIsALPWMEPZ15DSAabDaYxFM8OsP7XIW4uOVuDK9OEm1EqgrWAPVI8A0cJRfW4aAgTXEALw_wcB)
- [Plivo](https://www.plivo.com/)

They both have great APIs and run at less than an American penny.

For example, to send a text using Plivo:

```
$response = $client->messages->create(
    '14153336666',
    '14156667777',
    'Test Message'
);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are no free services but very very cheap services available for SMS. These cheap services are usually locale to a country.

Like Nigeria has BulkSmsNigeria, etc. Suggest you to google for "send sms services" and you'll find many.

Now using them in Laravel is a cakewalk with the [Laravel SMS API Plugin](https://github.com/gr8shivam/laravel-sms-api). It integrates with the Laravel notification system as well. Go through the plugin documentation for an easy understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SMSFactor](https://smsfactor.com)'s API alongside with their [Laravel Package](https://github.com/smsfactor/smsfactor-laravel) to easily send SMS. You just need to create an account that comes with 10 free SMS so you can try it out. Then sending an SMS would look like this:

```php
Message::send([
    'to' => '33600000000',
    'text' => 'Did you ever dance whith the devil in the pale moonlight ?'
]);
print_r($response->getJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending text message , there are several laravel packages available , i basically do use VONAGE package for sending text message .

- register on vonage's official site
- add test number
- create your route
- set up your controller according to your requirement as shown below .

[image]

For better understanding you can also read the full article [sending text message from laravel](https://www.studywithkishan.online/2020/09/Send%20SMS%20Using%20Nexmo%20in%20Laravel%207.html)